# Django url name, some points I'm not sure about

Tags: django, django-urls

I'm following the steps of the django tutorial (part 4).
And I'm [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial04/).
There is this tag :

```
{% url 'polls:vote' question.id %}
```

which triggers the following line in the urls.py file :

```
url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
```

I want to be sure about these points :

1. `question.id` is the value passed to the template engine to render
   the template.
2. The variable part (`(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)`) in the regex will be
   replaced by the first argument in the `url` tag (`question.id`).
3. The name of the variable part (`question_id`) is just the name the view will use to
   handle this value (as an argument). So this variable part may have no name (like just
   `r'^([0-9]+)/vote/$'`).
4. There could be several variable parts (and then several arguments
   passed to `{% url %}` tag).

Could anyone confirm this?

Thank you!

Comment: 1) `question` is past I guess, but you can access its attributes using dot notation, e.g. `question.id` or `question.pub_date`. 3) add brackets `r'^([0-9]+)/vote/$'` 4) yes :) but don't confuse non-named groups and named group, i. e. this will not work `r'^([0-9]+)(?P<foo>[a-z]+)/$'`

Comment: 3) I'll edit this :) Thanks for the rest!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

1. question.id in the url tag is the value passed to the url pattern via the view. The template is specified in the view, but this value ensures a unique object (question) in the context.
2. Correct
3. The name of the view is "vote" not question_id. This is shown in the url pattern (views.vote)
4. You can pass as many values as needed via the url tag in order to match up with your pattern. Just ensure these values are made available via your view.

Comment: 3) I'm not talking about the name of the view, but the name of the arg (So is this point correct, this way?). Thank you for the rest though. :)

Comment: Yes, you should be able to pass in the question id without an explicit declaration provided it meets the regex requirements. I'd avoid doing this because it isn't clear what you're expecting.